# How to pass array value in url

Tags: php, javascript

**Array :-**

```
 foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($relatedProduct->getId());
        $skus = $_product->getSku(); //get name
        $array[] = $skus;
    }
$str = serialize($array);
$strenc = urlencode($str);
```

**URL :-**

```
<script>
    function onTryonClick(argument) {
var url = "https://modakatech.com/camweara_vaibhav/index.php?skus=<?php echo $strenc; ?>&lengths=<?php echo $lengths;?>&cat=<?php echo $catlast;?>";
alert(url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($relatedProduct->getId());
        $skus = $_product->getSku(); //get name
        $array[] = "sku[]=".$skus;
    }
```

Now in your script, use this:

```
<script>
    function onTryonClick(argument) {
var url = "https://modakatech.com/camweara_vaibhav/index.php?<?php echo $implode("&",$array); ?>&lengths=<?php echo $lengths;?>&cat=<?php echo $catlast;?>";
alert(url);
</script>
```